# Filtering JSon using GSON and lambda

Tags: java, java-8, gson

I have huge json of the below sample format . I want to filter all items where "d1" equals "St" . I want to delete that object also in case no items are left because of above filtering .

```
[
{
  "containertype": "check2",
  "item": [
    {
      "d1": "St"
    },
    {
      "d1": "Pt"
    },
    {
      "d1": "St"
    }
  ],
  "contenttype": "test"
},
{
  "containertype": "check2",
  "item": [
    {
      "d1": "St"
    },
    {
      "d1": "St"
    },
    {
      "d1": "st"
    }
  ],
  "contenttype": "test"
}
```

]

Expected Result

```
[
{
  "containertype": "check2",
  "item": [

    {
      "d1": "Pt"
    }
  ],
  "contenttype": "test"
}
```

]

This is what i have tried , i am reading the json , using Gson , i got the map now i am trying to filter the items where the condition is met  . :

```
    public class Testing {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    try {
        final String json = "[{"containertype":"check2","item":[{"d1":"St"},{"d1":"Pt"},{"d1":"St"}],"contenttype":"test"},{"containertype":"check2","item":[{"d1":"Pt"},{"d1":"Pt"},{"d1":"Pt"}],"contenttype":"test"}]";
         Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type rowListType = new TypeToken<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {
        }.getType();
final List<Map<String, Object>> rows = gson.fromJson(json, rowListType);
            rows.stream()
                    .filter(r -> r.containsKey("item"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(rows, rowListType));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you compile it (without errors)? I doubt that the JSON String is declared valid: `final String json = "[{"containertype":"check2", ..` has un-escaped double-quotes inside. This is valid for JSON, BUT they must be escaped inside a String literal.

Answer (score 2):

### Define some POJO classes

JSON is meant to be read/deserialized into some objects. Thus *Gson* (or alternatively Jackson) called **mapper**. They map JSON to POJO (plain old Java objects).

So let's define the model.
For simplicity used Lombok (constructors, getter/setter, toString).

#### Item

```java
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Item {

    private String d1;

}
```

#### Container (containing *items*)

Additionally used Gson's annotation to obey Java-naming-convention (camelCase) while allowing your specified field-names (lower-case).

```java
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.List;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Container {

    @SerializedName("containertype")
    private String containerType;
    @SerializedName("item")
    private List<Item> items;
    @SerializedName("contenttype")
    private String contentType;
}
```

### Add functionality to a service-class

#### Map some JSON to containers

Using a Type-reference to let Gson know what objects to create.

```java
Type containerListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Container>>(){}.getType();
gson = new Gson();
List<Container> containerList = gson.fromJson(json, containerListType);
```

#### Filter out containers that do have items matching the specified criterion

using a *functional* Predicate and *streaming* (Java 8):

```java
    public static Predicate<Item> itemWhereD1equalsSt = item -> "St".equals(item.getD1());

    public static Predicate<Container> containerHasItemsWhereD1equalsSt = container -> {
        List<Item> items = container.getItems();
        if (items != null) {
            boolean hasItemMatching = items.stream().anyMatch(itemWhereD1equalsSt);
            return hasItemMatching;
        }
        return false;
    };

    public List<Container> filterFromJson(List<Container> containerList, Predicate<Container> containerPredicate) {
        return containerList.stream()
                .filter(containerPredicate)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

#### Remove items that match the specified criterion

Using the *stream-based* and *functional* convenience-method on List (Java 8):

(a) The simple variant (predicate inlined using *lambda expression*):

```java
    public void removeItemsSimple(List<Container> containers) {
        for (Container container : containers) {
            container.getItems().removeIf(item -> item.getD1().equalsIgnoreCase("St"));
        }
    }
```

(b) The enhanced variant (pass as param the predicate, we used already with containers):

```java
    public List<Item> removeItemsBasedOnFilter(List<Container> containers, Predicate<Item> itemPredicate) {
        return containers.stream()
                .flatMap(container -> removeItemsBasedOnFilter(container, itemPredicate).stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public List<Item> removeItemsBasedOnFilter(Container container, Predicate<Item> itemPredicate) {
        // Optional: filter all items in container that should be removed
        List<Item> itemsToBeRemoved = container.getItems().stream()
                .filter(itemPredicate)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // remove all items that match the predicate
        container.getItems().removeIf(itemPredicate);

        // Optional: return removed items
        return itemsToBeRemoved;
    }
```

#### Complete service-class

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class JsonFilter {
    private static final Type containerListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Container>>(){}.getType();
    public static Predicate<Item> itemWhereD1equalsSt = item -> "St".equals(item.getD1());

    public static Predicate<Container> containerHasItemsWhereD1equalsSt = container -> {
        List<Item> items = container.getItems();
        if (items != null) {
            boolean hasItemMatching = items.stream().anyMatch(itemWhereD1equalsSt);
            return hasItemMatching;
        }
        return false;
    };

    private final Gson gson;

    public JsonFilter() {
        gson = new Gson();
    }

    public List<Container> readContainers(String json) {
        List<Container> containerList = gson.fromJson(json, containerListType);
        return containerList;
    }

    public List<Container> filterFromJson(List<Container> containerList, Predicate<Container> containerPredicate) {
        return containerList.stream()
                .filter(containerPredicate)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public void removeItemsSimple(List<Container> containers) {
        for (Container container : containers) {
            container.getItems().removeIf(item -> item.getD1().equalsIgnoreCase("St"));
        }
    }
    public List<Item> removeItemsBasedOnFilter(List<Container> containers, Predicate<Item> itemPredicate) {
        return containers.stream()
                .flatMap(container -> removeItemsBasedOnFilter(container, itemPredicate).stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public List<Item> removeItemsBasedOnFilter(Container container, Predicate<Item> itemPredicate) {
        // Optional: filter all items in container that should be removed
        List<Item> itemsToBeRemoved = container.getItems().stream()
                .filter(itemPredicate)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // remove all items that match the predicate
        container.getItems().removeIf(itemPredicate);

        // Optional: return removed items
        return itemsToBeRemoved;
    }

}
```

#### Tested

using *JUnit5* without assertions - just printing to console.

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import java.util.List;

class JsonFilterTest {

    @Test
    void filterContainerList() {
        final String json = givenJson(); // your test-data

        final JsonFilter jsonFilter = new JsonFilter();

        // map JSON to a list of containers
        List<Container> containersRead = jsonFilter.readContainers(json);

        // first filter-out all containers that do not have specified items
        List<Container> containersFiltered = jsonFilter.filterFromJson(containersRead, JsonFilter.containerHasItemsWhereD1equalsSt);
        System.out.println("Filtered containers resulting: " + containersFiltered.size());

        // then remove specified items from these resulting containers
        List<Item> itemsRemoved = jsonFilter.removeItemsBasedOnFilter(containersFiltered, JsonFilter.itemWhereD1equalsSt);
        System.out.println("Removed items: " + itemsRemoved.size());
    }

    private String givenJson() {
        return "[\n" +
                "  {\n" +
                "    \"containertype\": \"check2\",\n" +
                "    \"item\": [\n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "        \"d1\": \"St\"\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "        \"d1\": \"Pt\"\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "        \"d1\": \"St\"\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "    ],\n" +
                "    \"contenttype\": \"test\"\n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  {\n" +
                "    \"containertype\": \"check2\",\n" +
                "    \"item\": [\n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "        \"d1\": \"Pt\"\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "        \"d1\": \"Pt\"\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "        \"d1\": \"Pt\"\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "    ],\n" +
                "    \"contenttype\": \"test\"\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, don't display the old "ROW" but the new object you create after the stream

secondly, I added a filter in which I throw List -> Map-> and change the values into an item and check if there are any others that meet the criterion

below my solution -> example

```
List<Map<String, Object>> newRows = rows.stream()
        .filter(r -> r.containsKey("item"))
        .filter(r -> {
          List<Map<String, String>> item = (List<Map<String, String>>) r.get("item");
          List<Map<String, String>> newList = item.stream().filter(x -> !x.get("d1").toUpperCase().equals("ST")).collect(Collectors.toList());
          r.put("item", newList);
          return !newList.isEmpty();
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(gson.toJson(newRows));
```

here is the test of my example

I used your example to test

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class GsonLambda {
  @Test
  public void test() {
    //given
    final String json = getJson();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type rowListType = new TypeToken<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {
    }.getType();
    final List<Map<String, Object>> rows = gson.fromJson(json, rowListType);
    //when
    List<Map<String, Object>> newRows = rows.stream()
            .filter(r -> r.containsKey("item"))
            .filter(r -> {
              List<Map<String, String>> item = (List<Map<String, String>>) r.get("item");
              List<Map<String, String>> newList = item.stream().filter(x -> !x.get("d1").toUpperCase().equals("ST")).collect(Collectors.toList());
              r.put("item", newList);
              return !newList.isEmpty();
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    //then
    assertEquals("[{\"containertype\":\"check2\",\"item\":[{\"d1\":\"Pt\"}],\"contenttype\":\"test\"}]", gson.toJson(newRows));
  }

  @NotNull
  private String getJson() {
    return "[\n" +
            "{\n" +
            "  \"containertype\": \"check2\",\n" +
            "  \"item\": [\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"d1\": \"St\"\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"d1\": \"Pt\"\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"d1\": \"St\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  ],\n" +
            "  \"contenttype\": \"test\"\n" +
            "},\n" +
            "{\n" +
            "  \"containertype\": \"check2\",\n" +
            "  \"item\": [\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"d1\": \"St\"\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"d1\": \"St\"\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"d1\": \"st\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  ],\n" +
            "  \"contenttype\": \"test\"\n" +
            "}" +
            "]";
  }
}
```